# Get struct from line parsing

Tags: c++, parsing

does anybody know how to get struct from line? For example, i have struct:

```
struct Variable {
    Variable(){}
    string m_name = "";
    uint_16 value = 0;
    string comments = "";
}
```

And some variants of line:

```
string line = "foo 0x22 #Comments"; //hex value
```

or

```
string line = "foo 222 #Comments"; //decimal value
```

or

```
string line = "foo ((1<4)&2) #Comments"; //expression value
```

or

```
string line = "foo ((1<4)&2)"; //without comment
```

The question is, should i use syntax analysis? Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering how you anticipate interpreting `"((1<4)&2)"` as a `uint_16`

Comment: Stick it into a `stringstream` and use `>>` or `getline()` on it. It should handle strings, and numbers in both hex and decimal. The expression is really tricky though and you're going to need a full expression parsing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your fields are separated by a common delimiter (And that I've understood your question correctly), just break up the input string at the delimiters and consume them with string conversion functions. something like:

```
Variable parseVariable(const std::string& line)
{
   Variable variable;

   // You must define 'split'
   std::vector<std::string> inputFields = split(line, " ");
   variable.m_name = inputFields[0];

   // You must also define 'convertStringToUint16'
   variable.value = convertStringToUint16(inputFields[1]);

   if(inputFields.size() > 2)
   {
      variable.comments = inputFields[2];
   }

   return variable;
}
```

Disclaimer: this code has not been tested

Now, regarding your use of the term "expression" I am worried that you may want to be able to evaluate arbitrary expressions for the value variable. If so, I recommend you define a VERY small scope of expressions that can be evaluated, as even simple mathematical expressions require decent work to process correctly.